# Node.js chatbox - load a couple of last messages from db

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using node.js, and I'm trying to make chat based on steam id64. If user connect to chat, server will send last 2 messages from MySQL database. Onyly thing i see on website is 2 same messages.

```
function getSteamName(steamid, callback) {
    if (typeof steamid !== 'undefined') {
        var url = "steam api link, because under 10 reputation points" + steamKey + "&steamids=" + steamid;
        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }, 
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                callback(body.response.players[0].personaname);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

getSteamAvatar is pretty much this same but other link to steam API

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT "+count;
connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
    rows.reverse();
    for (row in rows) {
        console.log(row);
        var msg = rows[row];
        getSteamAvatar(msg.id64, function(userAvatar) {
            getSteamName(msg.id64, function(userNick) {
                msg["id64"] = userNick;
                msg["avatar"] = userAvatar;
                console.log(msg);
                socket.emit('chat message', msg);
            });
        });
    }
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

and in console I see:

```
0
1
RowDataPacket {
  id: 926,
  id64: 'Ezi',
  date: 2017-01-06T02:42:40.000Z,
  message: '454656',
  isDeleted: 0,
  rank: 'Admin',
  avatar: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c4/c410314bfdfe4fd23bac077212ee79adb99f6848_medium.jpg' }
RowDataPacket {
  id: 926,
  id64: 'Ezi',
  date: 2017-01-06T02:42:40.000Z,
  message: '454656',
  isDeleted: 0,
  rank: 'Admin',
  avatar: 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c4/c410314bfdfe4fd23bac077212ee79adb99f6848_medium.jpg' }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to see the latest two messages then please maintain the **status** field for **sent,read** so that you can easily fetch the latest messages.
>
> In your code you have console.log two times therefore it is giving two times in the message. Please cross check ..

Comment: This code is working. console.log is only for debug, but i can see only last message. I think it's because functions are waiting for steam api to response, but the for loop is seting 'row' variable to next number, but i don't know how to fix it.